# Using link_to remote: true to pass parameters to rails

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, link-to-remote

So I have a page with several messages, each with a link that changes (refines) the RATING of that message.  When a user clicks on this link, I want an AJAX call that updates the corresponding column value in the database for that message.  When this link is clicked, nothing should happen visibly.  There should be no page refresh or reload.

I've been trying to do this using link_to remote: true, but I can't seem to get it to work.  Documentation online is fairly unclear on this question and with the changes between Rails 2 and 3, some things like :with are no longer supported.

I've copied what I have so far, but I know its far from even coming close to a solution.
In terms of parameters I need passed into the database, I need the profile_id, the message_id and the new_rating.

Thanks in advance!

show.html.haml

```
.status-bar
  = link_to "", { action: :refine_result }, remote: true
```

profile_controller.rb

```
...

def refine_result
  @refinement = ResultRefinement.new
  @refinement.profile_id = params[:profile_id]
  @refinement.message_id = params[:message_id]

  @refinement.save

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render nothing: true }
    format.js { render nothing: true }
  end
end
```

result_refinement.rb

```
class ResultRefinement < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :profile_id, :message_id, :new_rating, :deleted

  belongs_to :profile
end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to set up a route for `ProfileController#refine_result` first.  Something like

```
match '/profile/refine_results' => 'profile#refine_results', :as => 'refine_results'
```

Then you can use

```
.status-bar
  = link_to "", refine_results_url(profile_id: 1, message_id: 100, new_rating: "awful"), remote: true
```

Comment: Awesome.  I got it to start passing the parameters and saving them into the database.
The only issue I'm still having is stopping the page from redirecting or changing.

Comment: It seems that another js file was overwriting the ajax.  Which is why I kept following the link rather than having ajax take over.